# How to limit Winston to only 1 file descriptor per log file

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

I'm currently using Winston in my project to log to a handful of log files - 4 different files to be exact.  Each file is leveraged by a large number of classes to group specific functionality - a pretty typical use case for an application.  My problem is that as of now, Winston is opening up a separate file descriptor for the same log file for every single class, every single time the class is even used.  I'm running on the most recent version of Amazon Linux and my baseline is 470 file descriptors in use.  As soon as I start up my application, I jump to over 1700.  From there, thousands of additional file descriptors are used as the app runs and instantiates new classes that utilize the loggers.  All our logs are pulled in using Winston's container (see code below).

Update: I just created a barebones app with ONLY winston, and I used it to create 1 parent logger and thousands upon thousands of child loggers.  I'm also using the child loggers to log a message when they're created.  This whole process only takes 1 file descriptor on the OS, so clearly something we're doing in our app (it's far more complex) is causing Winston to open a separate FD...but that's not the default behavior.  Has anyone seen this before?  I am working on adding more and more to the test app just to see if I can find the point when it actually starts using more file descriptors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well now I just feel stupid.  The issue had nothing to do with child loggers at all, creating a child logger definitely does not open a new file descriptor.  The issue was that we were always passing logger options to our loggers.get(id, options) method, rather than just passing the id with no options if the logger already existed.  The fix took all of a few lines of code and now we only have 1 file descriptor open per log file.  D'oh!

Answer (score 0):

> We have the method to retrieve a logger set up to be static, and so I'm starting to think that is the issue.

This only means that the class doesn't have to be instantiated to run that method.  It has no bearing on the lifetime of the return value.

The way I handle this is with a simple script where I export the Winston instance.  For example:

```
const winston = require('winston');

const applog = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)({ 
      level: 'debug',
      handleExceptions: true
    })
  ],
  format: winston.format.simple()
});

module.exports = applog;
```

Then, in any module where I want the logger, something like this:

```
const applog = require('./lib/applog');
```

Node.js caches the result of `require()`, so whatever you export is guaranteed to be the *exact same instance* for anywhere that the module is required.

You can adapt this method to your class and static method if you'd like.  Just do all of your Winston setup outside of the class (in that same file), and have the static method return the instance.

Comment: Winston provides the loggers.get method so we shouldn't even have to do this, it should simply store the file within the Winston container with a single open file descriptor.  The issue we're having is that various classes that use the same logger should have their log messages prefixed with different things for any log statement within that class only.  We've been handling that with child loggers which, for obvious reasons as mentioned above, won't work because it will drain our file descriptors.

Comment: @Evan Hmmm, there might be a bug in that child logger.  You might find this useful:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-annotate  It's a bit dated, but still works.

Comment: Oh cool, that looks interesting.  I’ll definitely take a look and report back - thanks!

Comment: @Evan Sounds good.  I have a build of it around here somewhere that supports metadata, for logging categories and what not to loggers that supported structured data, like Elasticsearch.  I'll see what I can dig up... I should really update that package, I had no idea anyone was using it!  :-)

Comment: I'm actually not entirely sure I'll be able to use this as is as much as I'd like to...it pretty much does exactly what I want, but I also need some pretty custom settings that are logger-specific including color themes, transports (with custom formatters), and a class -> log file mapping strategy.  I'll have to look at the code to see if this would be able to handle all that, but figured I'd mention it here first in case you have any helpful hints.  The issue is how we're creating the loggers and all the custom properties of each - would it help if I posted my entire LogService?

Comment: @Evan I think that all my code does is hook `debug`, `info`, `warn`, `error`, etc., and concatenate some text in front.  You could use a similar method rather than relying on the Winston built-in method.  In any case, I think you should narrow down the original issue you're having to a test case... if it turns out to be a bug in Winston, let 'em know on GitHub.